# Steuererklärung from Argentina. German Taxes

Tags: germany, taxes, argentina

I want to do my german Steuererklärung from Argentina. I was living in Germany until September last year. 
First I had to give the addresse of a friend in Germany, because they have to send me a password, and then they tell me that I can't do this from a computer in another country. I am using the software ELSTER. 
Did someone tried? 
thanks

Comment: Can you do this the old fashioned way, using physical paper forms? Otherwise, you might have to dig up a free German VPN.

Comment: by normal Post, do you mean? Maybe is the best way...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: This could have been posted on **Personal Finance & Money** (https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), as far as I can see.